# How can I break plywood off of the ground?

Tags: batman-arkham-city

There seems to be a lot of plywood walls off of the ground with Riddler Trophies behind them, and the Batclaw seems to have lost it's multi-line extension from Arkham Asylum. I've had limited success breaking them with the line launcher, but it doesn't always seem to work. Is there another way to break them, or am I just not finding the right positions to launch the line launcher from?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Find a higher spot close by, get to it, then jump off and do a regular glide into the plywood (Holding A in the Xbox 360 Version). Running into it from the glide will break the plywood, no need to do anything else.

Comment: Do you need to Dive Bomb for this or can you just do a regular glide?

Comment: You can punch in mid-air?

Comment: @FallenAngelEyes Edited to clarify. Regular glide.

Comment: @Ullallulloo No punch, just gliding into it will break it.

Comment: @DoozerBlake: Really? Okay, I'll check it out and accept if right.

Comment: You will know if Batman is going to break it in the glide because he will arch his feet forward to kick it in.

Answer (score 5):

There is one case in the latter half of the game where you will have to use the grapnel upgrade to zip up to break some plywood on a ceiling, but otherwise @DoozerBlake's solution stands for most of them.