# How do I get the elevator in the Wonder Tower Foundations to work?

Tags: batman-arkham-city

I've now defeated

> Rāʾs al-Ghūl

and on my way out of Wonder City, I noticed that the elevator in the Wonder Tower Foundations has now appeared. There is a panel with a green power symbol on the elevator that is lit up, but standing next to it gives me no "Use" option.

I've tried using my Cryptographic Sequencer as well, but it also has no effect. Its symbol hovers over the elevator control panel with a red circle with a slash through it (the typical "forbidden" symbol).

Do I need another type of weapon/hacking device (I don't have the one for TYGER panels yet) to use the elevator, or is it locked off until I hit a certain point in the plot?

Comment: Is it a spoiler that there's an elevator, or that it can work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need the upgrade that allows you access to TYGER panels to use the elevator; that's what the forbidden symbol is signifying. You'll use it soon after you break the structural weakness in [your other question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/34277/how-do-i-destroy-structurally-weak-areas-above-my-head/).