# How do I get the Riddler trophy above the wooden panelling in the collapsed streets?

Tags: batman-arkham-city

In the eastern-most collapsed streets on the way to Wonder City, just near the exit to the subway terminal, there’s a Riddler trophy hidden above some wooden panelling.

How do I break through the panelling to get it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aha - [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/92739/1095) made me figure it out. If you throw a freeze blast into the water far enough away from the edge of the platform, you’ll be able to rappel back onto the highest ledge, and double-tap the A button (XBox 360) to power glide up into the panelling and break it. You then use the Batclaw to get the trophy.

(Here’s hoping in the next game he can just throw a Batsledgehammer at stuff like this.)